# How to update the value of a single datapoint using https

Tags: https, httprequest, xively, datapoint

While the Xively API documentation and Libraries provide a good resource to read and write to Xively feeds and datastreams I cant seem to find a reference how to compose a https request to update a single datapoint.
For Example: To code a "button" on a web page that can change the value of a data point from 1 to 0, which triggers an action on the device that is connected to/with this Feed. i.e to compose a request directly in a browser to obtain the desired effect..
I am very new to this and any guidance to this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [XivelyJS](http://xively.github.io/xively-js/).

There is a full example of [a webpage](http://xively.github.io/xively-js/sample-app/) which uses WebSockets.

It's very easy to use.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xively-js/1.0.4/xivelyjs.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Set your API key first  
xively.setKey( "YOUR_KEY_HERE" );  

xively.datastream.update( "YOUR_FEED_ID", "test_datastream", 123, function( event, data ) {  
  console.log( data.current_value ); // Logs value changes in realtime  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link that looks like it may just work. Not all functionality appears to be working after porting to my own xively feed however..

Comment: Were you trying the sample app or something else?

Comment: Used the sample app with my own credentials/feeds and the like.

Comment: I suppose that some channels need to be created with initial values set before you hook up the JS app to it... Have you checked the console logs in your browser?

Comment: The feed are realtime sensors being updated every 30 seconds. The console log shows that some .png's are not loading as I did not import them into the file.The use.typekit.net files are not loaded as their location address is pointing to my local file (from where I am testing from) yet with a http address appended. Have checked the hrefs's they seem correct..  However when I change the temp on the app's interface the console shows the creation of a Temperature.json file. When I toggle the switches it does not. I am sure that I am overlooking something, appreciate any feedback..

Comment: Had a chance to look into this a bit more: I reverted the naming of the "light" switch back to the original version called "light" Upon doing so the console showed the creation of a light.json file, however nothing happened. In the mean time having changed the settings for the "music/ volume to my own feed was successful. It apears that the "switches" have some code in a file that does not allow their variables to be changed...I am sorry for not being able to perhaps use the right terminology I hope that my finding are helpfull to this great interface!!!